# How to use descending order in sort By created date

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, sorting, sort

I followed First answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237513/magento-sort-by-date-added), it is working fine.

**app/etc/modules/Stackoverflow_Catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackoverflow_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Stackoverflow_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Stackoverflow/Catalog/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Stackoverflow_Catalog_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Stackoverflow/Catalog/Model/Config.php**

```
<?php

class Stackoverflow_Catalog_Model_Config extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Config {
    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray() {
        $options = parent::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
        if (!isset($options['created_at'])) {
            $options['created_at'] = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Date');
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

but I want new products to show first, I mean Descending order, Please Let me know if any one has solution

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what you did, you can also rewrite the method: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addAttributeToSort()` and make it look like this:

```
public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
{
    //don't screw up the admin sorting.
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID) {
        return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
    }
    if ($attribute == 'create_at') {
        $newDir = ($dir == self::SORT_ORDER_ASC) ? self::SORT_ORDER_DESC : self::SORT_ORDER_ASC;
        return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $newDir);
    }
    return parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try a different approach by editing list.phtml and toolbar.phtml.

in list.phtml change

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()
```

to

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSort('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

And to sort products by date (old to new or new to old ) replace toolbar.phtml content with this:

```
<?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="toolbar">
    <?php if( $this->isExpanded() ): ?>
    <div class="sorter">
        <div class="sort-by"> 
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort by') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('position', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('position') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Featured </option>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Lowest Price </option>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Highest Price </option>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('name', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('name') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Name A-Z </option>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('name', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('name') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Name Z-A </option>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('entity_id', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('entity_id') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Newest to Oldest </option>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('entity_id', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('entity_id') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> Oldest to Newest </option>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('popularity', 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('popularity') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Popularity </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```